# How can have my OpenCV settings made the default for all my Visual Studio C++ projects?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv, visual-c++

Having to manually editing the settings for every new project I create is quite tedious.
And it is quite error prone so I sometimes forget to add something and a compile
error happens.

Is it possible to set up Visual Studio so that the settings I need for OpenCV are automatically applied to every new project?

By the way, I'm using Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Use property sheets (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774542%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Certainly under VS2012 you can set properties in microsoft.cpp.win32.user and they become global.
And according to this (and my vague memory) it works for VS2010 too:
http://www.curlybrace.com/words/2012/12/17/setting-global-c-include-paths-in-visual-studio-2012-and-2011-and-2010/

However, what I do is have a property sheet with all the OpenCV settings in it and when I create a new project I add the property sheet. (actually I have two, one for debug and one for release, although if I used conditional properties I would only need one.).
If I change versions of OpenCV I edit that property sheet and all my projects get the new settings.

Also see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsproject/archive/2009/06/23/inherited-properties-and-property-sheets.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Your should consider using [CMake](http://cmake.org) (as OpenCV itself does) for generating your project and solution files. It will allow you to (re-)generate your solution files on any machine in a consistent manner for multiple versions of IDEs and OpenCV updates.
All you need is a single `CMakeLists.txt` file along with your source code.

Comment: True. I'll rephrase. It's just that VS settings are horrible.

Answer (score 0):

You can *import/export* your project settings.
In Visual Studio(2010), goto `Tools -> Import and Export Settings..`
There you can, backup/save/export your current project settings. Now every time you create new project, import this setting and you won't need to repeat complete procedure.

Comment: Thank you! That's really useful. But if I'm changing my computer, the path file might have changed, so I'll probably still have to reset it again.

Comment: Welcome :). In any case, if you change your pc you have to at least once work on path settings. Apart from CMake and property sheet, I can suggest you to keep Environmental-Variable like path. It is very useful and handy.